# How to turn a Windows XP partition into a VirtualBox virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

How can I turn a hard drive with XP into a VirtualBox virtual machine?

Comment: Can you provide any more information? Do you want to install virtualbox on your XP system, do you want to move the XP drive into a virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox has a wiki (including step-by-step instructions) for you:

**[How to migrate existing Windows installations to VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows)**

Comment: I tried that twice (once via dd and once using the other method) with no luck.  Hopefully you have better luck!

Comment: There is a similar tutorial from Microsoft how to create a virtual hard disk from a physical windows installation to be used with MS VPC, those VHDs are compatible with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, the way to go might be [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) from System Internals.
It will make your Hard drive with XP into a virtual Hard drive which you can then import into a VM.