# how to convert partition into virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn a Windows XP partitioninto a VirtualBox virtual machine](https://superuser.com/questions/102313/how-to-turn-a-windows-xp-partitioninto-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)

My notebook cannot boot from my hdd anymore. I can connect the hdd to another computer and access the data.

Is there any way to convert system partition with Windows XP from hdd into virtual machine (VirtualBox preferably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have access to a linux system, maybe with a live disk, I think you can just us "dd" the partition to a file and use it as a VM

here is another resource which uses ghost http://arstechnica.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=338964