# Is it possible to port a working Windows XP system to a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

On my old laptop I have been using Windows XP for a really long time.

I have completed my switch from the old laptop to a new one (which has Windows 7 running on Intel i5 - the older laptop had Intel Core 2 Duo).

Though I rarely use my old laptop, quite often I need to open it up to run programs, which would otherwise require quite some time and an unreasonable effort to install on my new system.

Can I simply make an image of my old system and run it as a VM on my new laptop? Does VirtualBox have that kind of a feature?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to turn a Windows XP partition into a VirtualBox virtual machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/102313/how-to-turn-a-windows-xp-partition-into-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) from SysInternals.

Once you have the VHD file, simply mount it in its own VM.

[image: disk2vhd]

*(Image credit: SysInternals)*

Comment: Thanks! You give me hope! But can I use it with VirtualBox? I am googling it myself...

Comment: Yes, I've done it with several machines. VirtualBox opens VHDs as well as the other virtual hard disks it supports.

Comment: Got it! Will give it a shot. Seems like .vhd is a standard file format....

Comment: Yup. It works on Virtual PC as well, but that is very limited when it comes to multiple-CPU support, and with VirtualBox you can assign as many cores as you want.